Setting the Round properly
I have dataset like this



CC Receiver
Date




DIAB21C054
2023-01-03


DIAB21C054
2023-01-04


DIAB21C054
2023-01-05


DIAB21C054
2023-01-11


DIAB21C054
2023-01-12


DIAB21C054
2023-01-18


DIAB21C054
2023-01-19


DIAB21C054
2023-01-20


DIAB21C054
2023-01-26


DIAB21C054
2023-01-27



I want to make a new column called round, basically to see the pattern of every CC Receiver.
The main rules for setting the pattern is like this :

Working days are Monday to Saturday.
Sunday is a non-working day.
Holidays are also non-working days.
The round should only change if there is a gap of more than 1 working day between two consecutive dates (ignoring Sundays and holidays).

And this is my Holidays table



HolidayDate




2023-01-01


2023-01-22


2023-01-23


2023-02-18


2023-03-22


2023-04-07


2023-04-21


2023-04-22


2023-04-23


2023-04-25


2023-04-26


2023-05-01


2023-05-18


2023-06-01


2023-06-02


2023-06-04


2023-06-29


2023-07-07


2023-07-19


2023-08-17


2023-09-28


2023-12-25


2023-12-26


2024-01-01


2024-02-08


2024-02-09


2024-02-10


2024-02-14


2024-03-08


2024-03-09


2024-03-11


2024-03-12


2024-03-15


2024-03-29


2024-03-31


2024-04-10


2024-04-11


2024-05-01


2024-05-09


2024-05-10


2024-05-23


2024-05-24


2024-06-01


2024-06-17


2024-06-18


2024-07-07


2024-08-17


2024-09-16


2024-12-25


2024-12-26



So based on the rules,
I did this query :
WITH UniqueEntries AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [CC Receiver],
        [Date]
    FROM
        combined_output_zpay_view_harvesting
),
RankedEntries AS (
    SELECT 
        [CC Receiver],
        [Date],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [CC Receiver] ORDER BY [Date]) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        UniqueEntries
),
-- Step 1: Calculate the number of working days between consecutive dates
WorkingDayDifference AS (
    SELECT
        r1.[CC Receiver],
        r1.[Date],
        r2.[Date] AS NextDate,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, r1.[Date], r2.[Date]) - 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM master.dbo.spt_values v
            WHERE v.type = 'P' 
            AND DATEADD(DAY, v.number, r1.[Date]) < r2.[Date]
            AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, v.number, r1.[Date])) NOT IN ('Sunday') 
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM holidays h WHERE h.HolidayDate = DATEADD(DAY, v.number, r1.[Date]))
        ) AS WorkingDaysDiff
    FROM 
        RankedEntries r1
    LEFT JOIN RankedEntries r2
        ON r1.[CC Receiver] = r2.[CC Receiver] 
        AND r1.RowNum + 1 = r2.RowNum
),
-- Step 2: Identify when a new round starts
Rounds AS (
    SELECT
        wd.[CC Receiver],
        wd.[Date],
        CASE
            WHEN wd.WorkingDaysDiff > 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS IsNewRound
    FROM 
        WorkingDayDifference wd
    WHERE wd.NextDate IS NOT NULL
),
-- Step 3: Accumulate the round number
FinalRounds AS (
    SELECT
        [CC Receiver],
        [Date],
        SUM(IsNewRound) OVER (PARTITION BY [CC Receiver] ORDER BY [Date]) + 1 AS Round
    FROM 
        Rounds
)
SELECT
    [CC Receiver],
    [Date],
    Round
FROM
    FinalRounds
WHERE [CC Receiver] = 'DIAB21C054'
ORDER BY
    [CC Receiver], [Date];

And the result is still wrong like this:



CC Receiver
Date
Round




DIAB21C054
2023-01-03
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-04
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-05
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-11
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-12
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-18
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-19
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-20
2


DIAB21C054
2023-01-26
2


DIAB21C054
2023-01-27
2



Hence, it should be like this



CC Receiver
Date
Round




DIAB21C054
2023-01-03
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-04
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-05
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-11
2


DIAB21C054
2023-01-12
2


DIAB21C054
2023-01-18
3


DIAB21C054
2023-01-19
3


DIAB21C054
2023-01-20
3


DIAB21C054
2023-01-26
4


DIAB21C054
2023-01-27
4



I also see the other result:



CC Receiver
Date
Round




DIAB21C054
2024-02-10
14


DIAB21C054
2024-02-12
15



This is wrong, because 10th February are Saturday, and 12th February are Monday, so it has to be the same round, because Sunday are holiday, and it still in 1 working day different.

If you've got to the point of having a holiday table, why not go the full distance and have a calendar table instead? Holidays, Weekends and Working days can all be in that table and it makes these kind of tasks far easier.

Unless I'm missing something, you don't actually explain what your expected results are. You talk about round, but then go on about your business rules on what a working day is. How is that related to a CC Receiver's Date and the results you are after, which is an integer value?

This is like the simplest gaps and island problem, with only wrinkle is that you need to watch out for holidays and weekends. Calculate the "real" difference between date and next day depending on your business rules and then it's off to the races using the standard gaps-and-islands approach

@ThomA my expected result is what i've told on the question, basically it's to do the right round format for each CC Receiver

But you don't explain that logic, as I stated.

I think round is just some column name, not related to ROUND().

ya as @Luuk said it just a regular column, you can call it session, or season, or anything, sorry if take that as a Round()


Your sample data does not contain a Holiday   2) Focus on the calculation of a smaller part of your data, you start with 2023, and then claim it "does not work" in Februari 2024.   3)  Make the data more visual, start by creating a list and the minimal needed data to calculate your needed/wanted results (https://dbfiddle.uk/RO2ALQJq). Finally it's time to have a look at gaps-and-islands, which is (somewhere) on my list too.....


The use of the system table master.dbo.spt_values ​​is questionable because it contains only a limited number of rows. You must use a table that you control the values and the number of rows.... Create an tally table consisting of a single column and row numbered from 1 to n continuously (PK).

Best practice is to use a calendar table. This allows you to define dates, holidays, workdays, and workday sequence numbers in one central place. Once you have the calendar defined, workday sequence numbers can be obtained with a simple join and the number of elapsed workdays is just a subtraction. Your existing gaps and islands logic would then do the rest. See this answer for a further discussion of a similar case. See this db<>fiddle for an adaptation to your question.

You have a couple of problems in your code. First, you negate the date diff, so the next day diff isn't calculated correctly. So DATEDIFF(DAY, r1.[Date], r2.[Date]) - should be removed.
Secondly, you look into next day diff when calculating "round", but technically, it should look into the previous day to see if it's outside the range.
You can solve it by changing the Final round cte calc to: ISNULL(SUM(IsNewRound) OVER (PARTITION BY [CC Receiver] ORDER BY [Date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) + 1 AS Round
This will not count the current row into the calculation of new rounds, which should be pretty much what you're looking for.
I also changed the selection from spt_values to use a bit more sargable version: AND v.number < DATEDIFF(DAY, r1.[Date], r2.[Date]). Ideally though, you should not use this table at all, because it doesn't always exist and isn't documented.
Finally, you have: WHERE wd.NextDate IS NOT NULL which removes your last date. Remove that part.
The final output:
WITH UniqueEntries AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [CC Receiver],
        [Date]
    FROM
        (
    VALUES  (N'DIAB21C054', N'2023-01-03')
    ,   (N'DIAB21C054', N'2023-01-04')
    ,   (N'DIAB21C054', N'2023-01-05')
    ,   (N'DIAB21C054', N'2023-01-11')
    ,   (N'DIAB21C054', N'2023-01-12')
    ,   (N'DIAB21C054', N'2023-01-18')
    ,   (N'DIAB21C054', N'2023-01-19')
    ,   (N'DIAB21C054', N'2023-01-20')
    ,   (N'DIAB21C054', N'2023-01-26')
    ,   (N'DIAB21C054', N'2023-01-27')
) t ([CC Receiver],Date)

),
RankedEntries AS (
    SELECT 
        [CC Receiver],
        [Date],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [CC Receiver] ORDER BY [Date]) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        UniqueEntries
),
-- Step 1: Calculate the number of working days between consecutive dates
WorkingDayDifference AS (
    SELECT
        r1.[CC Receiver],
        r1.[Date],
        r2.[Date] AS NextDate,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM master.dbo.spt_values v
            WHERE v.type = 'P' 
            AND v.number < DATEDIFF(DAY, r1.[Date], r2.[Date])
            --AND DATEADD(DAY, v.number, r1.[Date]) < r2.[Date]
            AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, v.number, r1.[Date])) NOT IN ('Sunday') 
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (
    VALUES  (N'2023-01-01')
    ,   (N'2023-01-22')
    ,   (N'2023-01-23')
    ,   (N'2023-02-18')
    ,   (N'2023-03-22')
    ,   (N'2023-04-07')
    ,   (N'2023-04-21')
    ,   (N'2023-04-22')
    ,   (N'2023-04-23')
    ,   (N'2023-04-25')
    ,   (N'2023-04-26')
    ,   (N'2023-05-01')
    ,   (N'2023-05-18')
    ,   (N'2023-06-01')
    ,   (N'2023-06-02')
    ,   (N'2023-06-04')
    ,   (N'2023-06-29')
    ,   (N'2023-07-07')
    ,   (N'2023-07-19')
    ,   (N'2023-08-17')
    ,   (N'2023-09-28')
    ,   (N'2023-12-25')
    ,   (N'2023-12-26')
    ,   (N'2024-01-01')
    ,   (N'2024-02-08')
    ,   (N'2024-02-09')
    ,   (N'2024-02-10')
    ,   (N'2024-02-14')
    ,   (N'2024-03-08')
    ,   (N'2024-03-09')
    ,   (N'2024-03-11')
    ,   (N'2024-03-12')
    ,   (N'2024-03-15')
    ,   (N'2024-03-29')
    ,   (N'2024-03-31')
    ,   (N'2024-04-10')
    ,   (N'2024-04-11')
    ,   (N'2024-05-01')
    ,   (N'2024-05-09')
    ,   (N'2024-05-10')
    ,   (N'2024-05-23')
    ,   (N'2024-05-24')
    ,   (N'2024-06-01')
    ,   (N'2024-06-17')
    ,   (N'2024-06-18')
    ,   (N'2024-07-07')
    ,   (N'2024-08-17')
    ,   (N'2024-09-16')
    ,   (N'2024-12-25')
    ,   (N'2024-12-26')
) h (HolidayDate) WHERE h.HolidayDate = DATEADD(DAY, v.number, r1.[Date]))
        ) AS WorkingDaysDiff
    FROM 
        RankedEntries r1
    LEFT JOIN RankedEntries r2
        ON r1.[CC Receiver] = r2.[CC Receiver] 
        AND r1.RowNum + 1 = r2.RowNum
)
-- Step 2: Identify when a new round starts
,Rounds AS (
    SELECT
        wd.[CC Receiver],
        wd.[Date],
        CASE
            WHEN wd.WorkingDaysDiff > 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS IsNewRound
        ,WorkingDaysDiff
    FROM 
        WorkingDayDifference wd
  --  WHERE wd.NextDate IS NOT NULL
),
-- Step 3: Accumulate the round number
FinalRounds AS (
    SELECT
        [CC Receiver],
        [Date],
        ISNULL(SUM(IsNewRound) OVER (PARTITION BY [CC Receiver] ORDER BY [Date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) + 1 AS Round
        ,WorkingDaysDiff
    FROM 
        Rounds
)
SELECT
    [CC Receiver],
    [Date],
    Round,WorkingDaysDiff
FROM
    FinalRounds
WHERE [CC Receiver] = 'DIAB21C054'
ORDER BY
    [CC Receiver], [Date];

Outputs:



CC Receiver
Date
Round
WorkingDaysDiff




DIAB21C054
2023-01-03
1
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-04
1
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-05
1
5


DIAB21C054
2023-01-11
2
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-12
2
5


DIAB21C054
2023-01-18
3
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-19
3
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-20
3
4


DIAB21C054
2023-01-26
4
1


DIAB21C054
2023-01-27
4
0




I was just about to post a near identical answer, covering the same two points. Although a major rewrite to use a calendar table would be best practice, the above identifies the minimum changes needed to get the expected results. Only thing I would add is to change the AND DATEADD(DAY, v.number, r1.[Date]) < r2.[Date] condition to AND v.number < DATEDIFF(DAY, r2.[Date], r1.[Date]) to better limit the number of spt_values rows accessed. Using GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(DAY, r2.[Date], r1.[Date]) - 1) would be even better, if using SQL Server 2022 or later.

Yeah, good points @TN, i wanted mostly to make as little changes as possible, but added the numbers thing!
